# Nested loop to access dictionary Django HTML

Tags: django, loops, for-loop, django-templates, nested

I have list of Column title like this:

```
ColumnName = ['Latitude', 'Longitude', 'Depth']
```

and a dictionary with format like this:

```
MyDict = [{'Latitude': '75',
           'Longitude': '37',
           'Depth': 6.0},
          {'Latitude': '23',
           'Longitude': '97',
           'Depth': 2.3},
          {'Latitude': '55',
           'Longitude': '14',
           'Depth': 1.9}]
```

i want to make dynamic table with that data and access a dictionary value by its key from a list. And i have tried with this code in my django HTML but it doesnt work

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        {% for ColName in ColumnName %}
            <th> ColName <th>
        {% endfor %}
    <tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
        {% for i in MyDict %}
            <tr>
            {% for x in ColumnName %}
                <td>
                     {{i.x}}
                </td>
            {% endfor %}
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
</tbody>
</table>
```

If i access with

```
{{i.Latitude}}
```

it work, but if i access access that data with {{i.x}} it doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be to use a list of `(latitude, longitude, depth)` tuples instead of a list of dicts. In you view

```
def myview(request):
    the_dicts = get_the_dicts()
    # pep 08: variables should be all_lower + use plural for collections
    columns = ['Latitude', 'Longitude', 'Depth'] 
    data = [tuple(d[name] for name in column_names]) for d in the_dicts]
    return render(request, "yourtemplate.html", {"columns": columns, "data":data})
```

and in your template:

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        {% for colname in columns %}
            <th> colname <th>
        {% endfor %}
    <tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
        {% for row in data %}
            <tr>
            {% for value in row %}
                <td>{{value}}</td>
            {% endfor %}
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
</tbody>
</table>
```

The alternative (if you really want to use a list of dicts instead) requires writing a custom template filter or template tag that can do dynamic dict lookup, but this is more complicated and probably much slower too (3 tags or filters calls per dict in your list == significant overhead).

Answer (score 0):

can you try something like

```
{% for key, values in myDict.items %}
```

Comment: Dicts are not garanteed to be ordered before python 3.7.something

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Ah yes that is true. I was first thinking to use only the dict for both the colname and value but now that I see it, it will repeat the key.

Comment: Can you explain why one should try that? How does this code solve the problem? Keep in mind that others should be able to learn from your code